# CSS issue. Increasing the width of Span

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have made a button CSS where I need to see a content on hover.

The content is placed in a span with class="a-btn-slide-text" .But I am not being able to increase the width of the span. How to increase the size without hampering the other css classes?

Please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anvBa/

```
div class="content">
                <div class="button-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="a-btn">
                        <span class="a-btn-text">New Appraisal Type</span> 
                        <span class="a-btn-slide-text">
                            <input type="radio"/>Single Upload
                            <input type="radio"/>Bulk Upload
                        </span>

                        <span class="a-btn-icon-right"><span></span></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
```

CSS-

```
.content{
    position:relative;
    width:680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content .button-wrapper{
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.button-wrapper .a-btn{
    background:#80a9da;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(#80a9da,0),color-stop(#6f97c5,1));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #80a9da 0%, #6f97c5 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #80a9da 0%, #6f97c5 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #80a9da 0%, #6f97c5 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #80a9da 0%, #6f97c5 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80a9da', endColorstr='#6f97c5',GradientType=0 );
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:80px;
    height:38px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #5d81ab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(188,188,188,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(188,188,188,0.5);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(188,188,188,0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:10px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
.button-wrapper .a-btn-text{
    padding-top:5px;
    display:block;
    font-size:18px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    color:#446388;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s linear;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.a-btn-slide-text{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    right:52px;
    width:0px;
    background:#63707e;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px #363f49;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:38px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:-1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    box-shadow:-1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
    -webkit-transition:width 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:width 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition:width 0.3s linear;
    transition:width 0.3s linear;
}
.a-btn-icon-right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:52px;
    border-left:1px solid #5d81ab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4) inset;
    box-shadow:1px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4) inset;
}
.a-btn-icon-right span{
    width:38px;
    height:38px;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-20px 0px 0px -20px;
    background:transparent url(../images/arrow_right.png) no-repeat 50% 55%;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
    transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
.a-btn:hover{
    padding-right:180px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset, 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.a-btn:hover .a-btn-text{
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #5d81ab;
    color:#fff;
}
.a-btn:hover .a-btn-slide-text{
    width:100px;
}
.a-btn:hover .a-btn-icon-right span{
    opacity:1;
}
.a-btn:active{
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
    background:#5d81ab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4) inset;
    border-color:#80a9da;
}
```

Comment: How could you expect us to solve the issue without relevant code provided?

Comment: The code is exactly provided in the fiddle. Please have a look

Comment: Code needed to reproduce the problem should be included in the question itself. A jsfiddle is a useful addition, not a substitute.

Comment: I am new to this. so apologize for the errors. Have updated the code now. can I get help now

Answer (score 1):

Span is an inline element. It has no width or height.

So if you want to set height or width you have to set `display: block;` 
It will render it like a div as mentioned by Stefan.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I have been trying different ways. But not getting a solution.It would be very helpful if you can rectify the code and show me a link on fiddle

Comment: This will render it like a `div` instead of a `span`.

Comment: Thanks , got it cleared. I just said so as the dimension directive will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;`.  Inline elements normally cannot have their width specified.

```
.a-btn-slide-text {display:inline-block;width:...}
```

If you use `display:block;`' it will render the `span` like a `div`.

For the differences between `inline`, `block`, and `inline-block`, [go here](http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you trying to achieve. Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/anvBa/12/

I just added a Padding here and set width to 200px:

```
.a-btn:hover .a-btn-text{
    padding-right:200px;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #5d81ab;
    color:#fff;
}
.a-btn:hover .a-btn-slide-text{
    width:200px;
}
```